# Пример простой авторизации на Go

Tags: golang, auth

Покажите пожалуйста пример реализации простой авторизации по паролю и сохранении сессии на Go.

Comment: пока не чего не использую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейший пример с пакетами `github.com/gorilla/mux` и `github.com/gorilla/sessions`. Сначала `/` выдаст вам "you are anonymous", а после посещения `/login` выдаст "you are user". Остальное можете додумать сами.

```
var cookieStore = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))

const cookieName = "MyCookie"

type sesKey int

const (
    sesKeyLogin sesKey = iota
)

func main() {
    gob.Register(sesKey(0))

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/login", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ses, err := cookieStore.Get(r, cookieName)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        ses.Values[sesKeyLogin] = "user"
        err = cookieStore.Save(r, w, ses)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
    })
    router.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ses, err := cookieStore.Get(r, cookieName)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        login, ok := ses.Values[sesKeyLogin].(string)
        if !ok {
            login = "anonymous"
        }

        w.Write([]byte("you are " + login))
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В Go:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        url := "path/to/login.html"  //Страница входа
        if len(r.Header["Cookie"]) != 0 && r.Header["Cookie"][0] == "auth=your_MD5_cookies" {
            url = "path/to/index.html" //Страница после успешной авторизации
        }
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles(url); t.Execute(w, "")
    })
    http.Handle("/js/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("path/to")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

В login.html (c [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) и [jQuery-MD5](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/MD5-Hash-String.html)):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.md5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Логин: <input id="login" type="text" /></p>
    <p>Пароль: <input id="pwd" type="password" /></p>
    <button id="button">Войти</button>
    <script>
        $('#button').on('click', function () {
            var auth = $.MD5($("#login").val()+$("#pwd").val());
            Cookies.set("auth", auth);
            location.reload();
        });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

В index.html (c [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) и [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Успешная авторизация!</h1>
    <button id="button">Выйти</button>
    <script>
        $('#button').on('click', function () {
            Cookies.remove("auth");
            location.reload();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а какой там логин и пароль?